# Download Documents From Document Library with their security info

Tags: powershell, modified

I want to download all the documents from Document Library to a local drive. also I want their security info such as "Modified"", "Modified By" to be included in a CSV file.

I searched around net but couldn't get any useful PowerShell scripts.

if anyone is having such PowerShell script of C# code can share.

Comment: Have you got any code so far?

Comment: No. I am still searching for it. Trying to write my own PowerShell but no success so far. You have anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code to iterate through the list and get information of the items in the CSV file using PowerShell:

```
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://aissp2013:111"
$SPList = $SPWeb.Lists["Employee"]
$exportlist = @()
$SPList.Items | foreach {
$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
"Title" = $_["Title"]
"Name" = $_["Name"]
"Modified Date" = $_["Modified"]
}
$exportlist += $obj
$exportlist | Export-Csv -path 'C:\MyList.csv' -noType
}
$SPWeb.Dispose()
```

Source: http://shaiknb.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/powershell-sharepoint-export-list-items-via-view-to-csv/

The code for downloading documents from Document library is:

```
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://aissp2013:111"
$files = $SPWeb.GetFolder("Shared Documents").Files
foreach ($file in $files) {
    Write-host $file.Name
    $b = $file.OpenBinary()
    $fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream(("C:\temp\"+$file.Name), [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
    $bw = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($fs)
    $bw.Write($b)
    $bw.Close()
}
```

Make sure to create the folder **C:\temp** first.

Source: http://www.spjeff.com/2013/07/03/powershell-download-all-files-in-a-document-library/

Comment: Thanks Nadeem.one more issue.how can we have folder structure name in CSV file.

Comment: The Items property returns all the files in a document library, including files in subfolders, but not the folders themselves. In a document library, folders are not considered items. You may have to use something like foreach (SPListItem item in list.Folders) to get folder info.

Comment: What do you mean by path? Is it the url to display form of the item?

Comment: It should be something like this $url = $SPWeb.Url + "/Lists/Employee/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + "$_Id

Comment: can we keep log of each file downloaded with success or not in same CSV file?